# Check Number of Characters Of Textfield in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, character, textfield

I am new to SwiftUI and I need to call a **function** when user enters *minimum* **three characters** in a textfield.

Like this:

[image: simulator]

After **completing three or more** characters I want to perform a function. Is there any way to do this in *SwiftUI*?

Comment: An async function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .onChange :

```
.onChange(of: name) { newValue in
                    
                    if newValue.count >= 3 {
                        // Call function
                    }
}
```